# CentOS Kickstart Packages

Tags: centos, system-installation, kickstart, installer-anaconda

I'm trying to install CentOS7 using a kickstart file which I've written. Below is a snippet from the kickstart

```
##################################

##### 3. Package installation

##################################

repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/

%packages

base
core

man
git
ruby
rpm-build
apache-maven

%end
```

However, I'm receiving an error 
'You have specified that the package 'git' should be installed. This package does not exist. Would you like to continue the install without this package?

The installation is meant to be non-interactive but I'm assuming if the package was available it would continue. I've typed 'continue' for git and every package in the above list was also unavailable.

How do I enable the yum repos or fix this problem during OS installation?

Comment: Does your kickstart have a `url` statement? If so, what is that pointing at? Or, does it have any `repo` statements?

Comment: It does indeed. I've edited the question. Unfortunately it's still not picking up any of the packages.

Comment: What happens if you use a `url --url=http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/` entry and remove that `repo` line? (I usually instead point kickstarts to a local copy of the same, for better predictability.)

Comment: @thrig I managed to get it working tweaking the repo/urls !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no repo or url specified. The installation continued with the following snippet for the packages

```
##################################

##### 3. Package installation

##################################

url --url="http://sunsite.rediris.es/mirror/CentOS/7/os/x86_64/"
repo --name="CentOS" --baseurl="http://mirror.centos.org/centos/7/os/x86_64/"
repo --name="EPEL" --baseurl="http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/beta/7/x86_64/"

%packages

@base
@core

man
git
ruby
maven
rpm-build

%end
```